# Using AWS ECS Placement Constraints with instance tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to constrain the placement of ECS tasks based on instance tags? I have EC2 instances in the ECS cluster that are tagged, and would like to use this to ensure certain tasks run on those instances? I don't see how it can be done.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html

Comment: How are you creating the instances? You'd normally do this by using ECS instance attributes and then use a placement constraint on that custom attribute. Normally this would either be baked into the AMI or set using user data.

Comment: I am creating instances using terraform. This is the solution I have started using. I am setting a custom attribute via user data then using a placement constraint.

Comment: @JamesMudd Do you happen to have an answer with an example that you could post to this question?

Comment: @eltiare Have added an answer with a small example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet of Terraform config to illustrate how to implement this approach

```
data aws_ssm_parameter amazonLinux2 {
  name = "/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id"
}

resource aws_instance elasticsearchInstance {
  ami = data.aws_ssm_parameter.amazonLinux2.value
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.ecsPrivateSubnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_agent.name

  user_data = <<EOT
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ECS_CLUSTER=clusterName' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo 'ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={"type": "elasticsearch"}' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
EOT
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "elasticsearchTask" {
  family = "elasticsearch"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "elasticsearch"
      image     = "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2"
      cpu       = 2048
      memory    = 3942
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 9200
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
  placement_constraints {
    type       = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:type == elasticsearch"
  }
}
```

The is not a full configuration, but the core bits are setting the `user_data` to add `ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES` in this case `type=elasticsearch` and then adding `placement_constraints` to the task definition that forces the task onto the instance.